# C# Procedural Generation - Check for neighbours

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, procedural-generation

As part of some procedural generation code, I have a function that checks if a cell in a grid has any neighbouring cells.

The grid is a 2D array, if it was printed it would look like this (# = cell and . = empty and the # around the edge is a border):

```
 0123456789
0##########
1#........#
2#........#
3#........#
4#........#
5#....##..#
6#........#
7#........#
8#........#
9##########
```

So, for example, my code returns true if it checks cell 5,5.

The code I have written for checking for neighbouring cells  works, but does not take into account if the cell it is checking is at the "edge" (eg. 0,0 or 0,1 or 10,10) and will create out of bound errors if it does check cells at the edge. I'm unsure of how to go about writing code that does take this into account, any advice would be appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
public static bool HasNeighbour(int[,] array, int CellX, int CellY)
{

    if (array[CellX + 1, CellY] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX - 1, CellY] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX, CellY + 1] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX, CellY - 1] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX + 1, CellY + 1] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX + 1, CellY - 1] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX - 1, CellY + 1] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (array[CellX - 1, CellY - 1] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, is there a more efficient version of my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (bounds check included):

```
public static bool HasNeighbour(int[,] array, int CellX, int CellY) {
  for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i)
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
      if ((i != 0) && (j != 0)) {
        int x = CellX + i;

        if ((x < 0) || (x >= array.GetLength(0)))
          continue;

        int y = CellY + j;

        if ((y < 0) || (y >= array.GetLength(1)))
          continue; 

        if (array[x, y])
          return true;
      }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Could you explain which part is the bound checks, I'm guessing it's the parts with "array.GetLength()"?

Comment: yes, you are quite right: x should be within [0..array.GetLength(0) - 1] when y should be within [0..array.GetLength(1)]

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you explain the two for loops, I'm not clear of what they are for? Thanks

Comment: well, x should be in [CellX - 1..CellX + 1] range, while y should be in [CellY - 1..CellY + 1] range - that's loop origin. Sure, array[CellX, CellY] is not a neighbour, it's a position itself, that's why I check "if ((i != 0) && (j != 0))"